# How can I insert an array to database table with new rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert an array size 2000 into a database table that contains 13 columns, from array[0] to array[12] in the first row then from array[13] to array[25] in the second row ..... 
this is the command that contains the columns name but i can't get how to arrange a for loop to insert in the table, below my try and it is not working.
i have searched the internet but i couldn't find and understand the proper way, appreciate your assistant

```
string shpttrackingSql = ("INSERT INTO shpttrackingTable Values (@Checkpoint, @Stn, @Location," +
"@DateTime, @Pcs, @Route, @Cycle, @Stat, @Pgln, @Count, @Last, @Remarks, @Comments)");

// Inserting data from array to Tracking Table
SqlCommand shpttrackingCmd = new SqlCommand(shpttrackingSql, con);

for (int i=0;i<2000;i++)
            {
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkpoint", trackingArray[i]); //Checkpoint
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stn", trackingArray[i]); //Stn
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", trackingArray[i]); //Location
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", trackingArray[i]); //Date and Time
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pcs", trackingArray[i]); //Pieces 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Route", trackingArray[i]); //Route
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cycle", trackingArray[i]); //Cycle
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stat", trackingArray[i]); //Stat
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pgln", trackingArray[i]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", trackingArray[i]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", trackingArray[i]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", trackingArray[i]); //Remarks
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", trackingArray[i]); //Comments

                con.Open();
                shpttrackingCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: hmmm 13 cols and array size 2000 ... do you have `153,8461538461538` rows? ... anyway what is wrong with `trackingArray[i], trackingArray[i+1]... trackingArray[i+12]` and incrementing `i` by `13`?

Comment: does the for loop add new row because I am facing this error "The variable name @Checkpoint has already been declared. variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure" and i didn't declare this variable before

Comment: that's because you are adding parameters in loop ... you can: 1. add it once outside the loop and then only set values (better) (also move Open Close, outside the loop)  2. create new instance of SqlCommand in the loop and add params there(will work-not recommended)

Comment: What is the data type of `trackingArray`?

Comment: string trackingArray

Comment: i have solve it by adding       shpttrackingCmd.parameter.clear() after the ExecuteNonQuery inside the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the parameters inside the loop by adding
    shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.Clear(); inside the loop as below

```
for (int i=13;i<53;i+=13)
            {
                str = trackingArray[i+0];
                str = str.Replace("\r\n                </a>", "").Trim();
                substr = str.Substring(str.Length - 30).Trim();
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checkpoint", substr); //Checkpoint

                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stn", trackingArray[i+1]); //Stn
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", trackingArray[i+2]); //Location
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", trackingArray[i+3]); //Date and Time
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pcs", trackingArray[i+4]); //Pieces 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Route", trackingArray[i+5]); //Route
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cycle", trackingArray[i+6]); //Cycle
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stat", trackingArray[i+7]); //Stat
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pgln", trackingArray[i+8]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count", trackingArray[i+9]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", trackingArray[i+10]); 
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", trackingArray[i+11]); //Remarks
                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", trackingArray[i+12]); //Comments

                con.Open();
                shpttrackingCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                shpttrackingCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
```